# Weird animation effects in tab bar

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, navigation

When navigating through the app there is a weird animation effect happening on the tab bar.

Video: https://youtu.be/JJ5Fl-L0clQ
*You will need to force it to play in a high quality to see properly*

App version: 1.3.2.225
iOS version 9

Comment: What device are you running? I'm not able to reproduce that on my devices, though I suspect its an issue with the snapshotting.

Comment: iPhone 6, you have to be on a specific site from the nav on the left. Then pressing any question and navigate back has a 100% reproduce for me.

Comment: Hmm... I'll try only snapshotting the subviews and see what that does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will hopefully be fixed in the next build.  I have no idea what's causing it but I'm hoping that just [cloning the tab bar items and not the tab bar](https://github.com/bnickel/HidingTabBar/commit/95a5d3b5c5add5d02592adeb0e972d66be5b51d5) will fix it.

Comment: Yeah fixed in 227